# JTextPane in a JScrollPane doesn't react to mouse wheel

Tags: java, swt, awt

I used the following structure in my (SWT) java app:

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite contains a
  org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.CTabFolder contains zero to n
    org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem contains a
      org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.Composite contains a
        java.awt.Frame (created by SWT_AWT.new_Frame()) contains a
          javax.swing.JTextPane and a
          javax.swing.JScrollPane
```

Everything works just fine, the text in the text pane scrolls when I drag the scroll bar and is drawn just fine, but the mouse wheel just doesn't move the scroll bar. If I add a mouse wheel listener to the text pane, the event never reaches my code. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Did you call jScrollPanel.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true) method?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't ... but now that I do, it still doesn't work. Is there another "DoWhatIWant" flag somewhere?